# How to set a hidden field value on a page from other page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have one page(suppose first page) where I have a `hidden Field` control. Now from this page I need to go to another page(second page), but I am not using `window.open` method instead of that I am using `document.form.submit()` method. Now from second page I need to set the value of hidden Field which is on first page.
Because I am not using `window.open()` method so I can not use parent.window.opener for setting the value of hidden field.
So is there any way I can set the hidden field value from second page to first page.
(Again I am using `document.form.submit()` method from second page to go to first page).

Thanks.

Comment: you have to use some server side scripting like php, jsp etc

Comment: If you *submit* the form on page 1, add the *hidden* field to page 1 form, it'll be seen on page 2. There you can add it again as hidden field, if you please.

Answer (score 0):

You should use server side code to get the values submitted from previous page.
    The form values automatically send the values in the form

OR

If you use get method, with the help of javascript you can get and assign the values

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Answer (score 0):

By Using SERVER Side Scripting Language like **`PHP, ASP, JSP`** etc.
Below is the example of PHP scripting language.

```
<form action="first.php"> ... </form>
```

In first.php:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['your input textbox name']; // if you define the **METHOD** as **GET** of form html element

or

echo $_POST['your input textbox name']; // if you define the **METHOD** as **POST** of form html element

or

even you can use like this: echo $_REQUEST['your input textbox name']; // it works for both **POST** or **GET**

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Form2 writes data to cookie or local db. 
Start a timer on form1 after you open form2, check the data continuously.